# Cannot delete row from FDTable, when fields are added to the field editor

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

- 1x FDConnection1 (Firebird 3)
- 1x FDTable
- 1x DataSource
- 1x DBNavigator
- 1x DBGrid

Table metadata:

```
AID   VarChar(8), (Primary key, not null)
ANAME VarChar(10);
```

I cannot delete records when I have added table fields. (Rightclick FDTable, Fields Editor, Add all fields)
I get this Error: [FireDac][DApt]-400. Delete command deleted [0] instead of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uFgw.png) record. Possible reasons: update table does not have PK or row identifier.

I am able to delete records when the fields is not added, but I need the fields to be added so I can control their behavior eg. display size, alignment.

What am I missing? I need help.

[image: This works when pressing Delete and no TField's added]

[image: This dont work when pressing Delete. Here is the TFields added]

Comment: Your q needs an MCVE (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add your code to your q. How are you attempting to do the delete, exactly? Btw, whether or not you use persistent TFields shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: There is no code at all, only the 5 components placed on a TForm and linked to eachother as usual.

Comment: I have build the project on both a Delphi XE10 and a Delphi 10.1 with same result. :(

Comment: @ITNET, in your FDTable set propertie IndexFieldName=AID

Comment: Thanks!, Actually the IndexFeildName was populated with AID. But after remove it works perfekt.

Comment: Well, it worked for my little test project. But somehow the tricks doesn't work on a bigger project. Have to investigate.